# Dictionary API (lexical)

Tags: c#, .net, api

Does anyone know a good .NET dictionary API? I'm not interested in meanings, rather I need to be able to query words in a number of different ways - return words of x length, return partial matches and so on...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Grab the flat text file from an open source spellchecker like ASpell (http://aspell.net/) and load it into a List or whatever structure you like.

for example,

```
List<string> words = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("MyWords.txt").Split(new string[]{Environment.NewLine}).ToList();

// C# 3.0 (LINQ) example:

    // get all words of length 5:
    from word in words where word.length==5 select word

    // get partial matches on "foo"
    from word in words where word.Contains("foo") select word

// C# 2.0 example:

    // get all words of length 5:
    words.FindAll(delegate(string s) { return s.Length == 5; });

    // get partial matches on "foo"
    words.FindAll(delegate(string s) { return s.Contains("foo"); });
```

Comment: I believe that code requires C# 3.0, and either .NET 3.5 or .NET 2.0 with LINQBridge. .NET 3.0 doesn't provide anything useful over .NET 2.0 in this respect.

Comment: True, I've been working in 3.0 for a while now, so I guess I'm getting pretty used to having LINQ handy when I need it.  Edited to contain non-3.0 samples.

Comment: Why can I only upvote once?  ;)

Comment: I browsed http://aspell.net/ but i cant find a flat text file. How can i get the flat text file? Do I have to install Aspell and search in the install directory for that file?

Comment: kiltek, I had a look and it looks like it was easier to find 7 years ago. :( Let us know if you figure it out.

Comment: @kiltek This command `aspell -d en dump master | aspell -l en expand > my.dict`  will generate a flat text file using aspell as answered here --> https://superuser.com/a/137990/1430 (however, I replaced `pl` with `en` for English)

Answer (score 4):

You might want to look for a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) implementation. That will certainly help with "words starting with XYZ" as well as exact matches. You may well want to have all of your data in multiple data structures, each one tuned for the particular task - e.g. one for anagrams, one for "by length" etc. Natural language dictionaries are relatively small compared with RAM these days, so if you really want speedy lookup, that's probably the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how involved your queries are going to be, it might be worth investigating [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/), which is basically a semantic dictionary.  It includes parts of speech, synonyms, and other types of relationships between the words.

Answer (score 2):

NetSpell (http://www.loresoft.com/netspell/) is a spell checker that's written in .NET that has word listings in several languages that you could use.

Answer (score 2):

I'm with [Barry Fandango](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335517/a-dictionary-api-for-c#335563) on this one, but you can do it without LINQ. .NET 2.0 has some nice filtering methods on the List(T) type. The one I suggest is

```
List(T).FindAll(Predicate(T)) : List(T)
```

This method will put every element in the list through the predicate method and return the list of words that return 'true'. So, load your words as suggested from an open source dictionary into a List(String). To find all words of length 5...

```
List(String) words = LoadFromDictionary();
List(String) fiveLetterWords = words.FindAll(delegate(String word)
    {
        return word.Length == 5;
    });
```

Or for all words starting with 'abc'...

```
List(String) words = LoadFromDictionary();
List(String) abcWords = words.FindAll(delegate(String word)
    {
        return word.StartsWith('abc');
    });
```

Comment: oh snap, he wrote the C# 2.0 code too... oooops. (note to self: read answers fully)